# binarization of numbers python

Tags: python, binary

I have feature that is a number and I want to catgorize all the possibility and making it a binary feature.

feature:

```
   FEATURE1
1  23
3  20
4  23
5  1
7  8
8  23
```

wanted input:

```
   FEATURE1   23   20 ....
1  23         1    0  .... 
3  20         0    1  ....
4  23         1    0  ....
5  1          0    0  ....
7  8          0    0  ....
8  23         1    0  ....
```

- I don't have a lot of different numbers

can you help?

Comment: What is the basis of the categorization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `pd.get_dummies()` function in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']})
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['X']))
print(df)
```

output:

```
   X  a  b  c
0  a  1  0  0
1  b  0  1  0
2  c  0  0  1
3  a  1  0  0
```

Comment: thank you! can I automatically add a string to the col name? (such as feature_a)

Comment: you can specify any prefix, here is the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using pandas pivot_table

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'FEATURE1': ['10', '13', '13', '22', '15']})  
df.pivot_table(index=df.index, columns='FEATURE1', aggfunc=len          
          ).fillna(value=0)
```